# How to improve speed of connecting to ActiveMQ HTTP transport

Tags: java, http, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

I have an Apache ActiveMQ broker with a HTTP transportConnector.
I try to connect java consumers to it.
After about 260 consumers the time to establish a connection increases linearly.
Cpu and memory usage remains low, so I don't understand what is going wrong.

- ActiveMQ broker version 5.11.1
- Java clients use org.apache.activemq:activemq-http:5.15.4

The transport is configured like this:

```
<transportConnector name="http" uri="http://0.0.0.0:8082"/>
```

Comment: Does the behavior change if you use a different transport connector? Just trying to see if the problem is the transport connector itself or something else within the broker.

Comment: Yes, the openwire protocol, with tcp or nio connector remains fast.

Comment: Have you attached any kind of profiling tool to the broker and/or the clients to see where all that time is being spent? Does the behavior change if the clients are on the same machine as the broker?

Comment: The slow parts are createConnection and createSession. They are very fast upto 250 clients and then gradually slow down. I haven't tried putting the clients on the same machine as the broker. This would require a rather beefy machine with lots of ram.

Comment: I haven't profiled the broker yet, but I think that might lead to interesting information.